# Flashdevelop AS3 2DPlatformer [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069:

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, 2d-games

I am currently working on a 2D Platformer and I get this Error message when I try to run the 
game: [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 1 not found on Number and there is no default value.
Fault, loadMap() at Main.as:253
Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem?

this is the entire code I have in main:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.events.TextEvent;
    import flash.globalization.Collator;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Umeer
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {   
        [Embed(source="../Assets/wip_parallax_background_by_stormandy-d5n5tr6.png")]
        public var BG:Class;
        private var cam:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        private var aDown:Boolean = false;
        private var dDown:Boolean = false;
        private var wDown:Boolean = false;
        private var sDown:Boolean = false;
        private var leftDown:Boolean = false;
        private var rightDown:Boolean = false;
        private var spaceDown:Boolean = false;
        private var char:Player = new Player();
        private var char2:Player2 = new Player2();
        private var bullets:Array = [];
        private var blocks:Array = [];
        private var coins:Array = [];
        private var coins2:Array = [];
        private var enemies:Array = [];
        private var keys:Array = [];
        private var doors:Array = [];
        private var ladders:Array = [];
        private var redwater1:Array = [];
        private var bluewater1:Array = [];
        private var climbing:Boolean = false;
        private var hp:HealthBar = new HealthBar(0x00FFFF);
        private var hp2:HealthBar = new HealthBar(0xFF0000);
        private var enhp:HealthBar = new HealthBar(0xFF6600);
        private var score:int = 0;
        private var keyCount:int = 0;
        private var current:int = 0;
        private var mapIndex:int = 0;
        private var textBox:TextField = new TextField();
        private var textStyle:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 18);
        private var enemyNameBox:TextField = new TextField();
        private var keyTextBox:TextField = new TextField();
        public var Restart:Replay;
        public var ShowEnd:TextField = new TextField();
        private var maps:Array = [
        [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 1, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 1]],
        [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
        ];
        private var styles:Array = [
        [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [1, false]],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, [1,5,0,200,0]],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
        [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [0, false]],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
        ];
        private var enemyNames:Array = ["Enemy 1" , "Enemy 2" , "Enemy 3" ];
        public function Main():void 
        {   
            var background:Bitmap = new BG();
            addChild(background);
            addChild(cam);
            hp.x = 150;
            hp.y = 23;
            addChild(hp);
            hp2.x = 500;
            hp2.y = 23;
            addChild(hp2);
            textBox.x = 10;
            textBox.y = 10;
            textBox.defaultTextFormat = textStyle;
            addChild(textBox);
            enemyNameBox.x = 300;
            enemyNameBox.y = 35;
            enemyNameBox.defaultTextFormat = textStyle;
            enemyNameBox.width = 300;
            keyTextBox.x = 400;
            keyTextBox.y = 10;
            addChild(keyTextBox);
            keyTextBox.defaultTextFormat = textStyle;
            addChild(enemyNameBox);
            char.x = 175;
            char.y = 300;
            cam.addChild(char);
            char2.x = 125;
            char2.y = 300;
            cam.addChild(char2);
            enhp.x = 300;
            enhp.y = 23;
            addChild(enhp);
            loadMap(0, -1);
            mapIndex = 0;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keysUp);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown2);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keysUp2);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, m2Down);
            cam.setChildIndex(char, cam.numChildren - 1);
        }
        public function loadMap(index:int,current:int)
        {
            if (cam.numChildren > 1)
            {
                while (cam.numChildren > 0)
                    cam.removeChildAt(0);
            }
            if (current != -1)
            {
                var newArr:Array = [];
                for (var i:int = 0; i < maps[current].length; i++)
                    newArr.push([]);
                for (var s:int = 0; s < maps[current].length; s++)
                {
                    for (var h:int = 0; h < maps[current][0].length; h++)
                        newArr[s].push(0);
                }
                for (var b:int = 0; b < blocks.length; b++)
                {
                    if (!block[b].mover)
                        newArr[(blocks[b].y - 25) / 50][(blocks[b].x - 25) / 50] = 1;
                    else    
                        newArr[(blocks[b].yHome - 25) / 50][(blocks[b].xHome - 25) / 50] = 1;
                }
                for (var c:int = 0; c < coins.length; c++)
                    newArr[(coins[c].y - 25) / 50][(coins[c].x - 25) / 50] = 2;
                for (var u:int = 0; u < coins2.length; u++)
                    newArr[(coins2[u].y - 25) / 50][(coins2[u].x - 25) / 50] = 7;
                for (var l:int = 0; l < ladders.length; l++)
                {
                    if (ladders[l].top)
                        newArr[(ladders[l].y - 25) / 50][(ladders[l].x - 25) / 50] = 6;
                    else 
                        newArr[(ladders[l].y - 25) / 50][(ladders[l].x - 25) / 50] = 5;
                }
                for (var d:int = 0; d < doors.length; d++)
                        newArr[(doors[d].y - 25) / 50][(doors[d].x - 25) / 50] = 8;
                maps[current] = newArr;
                newArr = [];
                for (var i:int = 0; i < maps[current].length; i++)
                    newArr.push([]);
                for (var s:int = 0; s < maps[current].length; s++)
                {
                    for (var h:int = 0; h < maps[current][0].length; h++)
                        newArr[s].push(0);
                }
                for (var b:int = 0; b < blocks.length; b++)
                {
                    if (!block[b].mover)
                        newArr[(blocks[b].y - 25) / 50][(blocks[b].x - 25) / 50] = 1;
                    else    
                        newArr[(blocks[b].yHome - 25) / 50][(blocks[b].xHome - 25) / 50] = [1,blocks[b].xSpeed,blocks[b].ySpeed,blocks[b].xDist,blocks[b].yDist];
                }
                for (var c:int = 0; c < coins.length; c++)
                    newArr[(coins[c].y - 25) / 50][(coins[c].x - 25) / 50] = 2;
                for (var u:int = 0; u < coins2.length; u++)
                    newArr[(coins2[u].y - 25) / 50][(coins2[u].x - 25) / 50] = 7;
                for (var l:int = 0; l < ladders.length; l++)
                {
                    if (ladders[l].top)
                        newArr[(ladders[l].y - 25) / 50][(ladders[l].x - 25) / 50] = 6;
                    else 
                        newArr[(ladders[l].y - 25) / 50][(ladders[l].x - 25) / 50] = 5;
                }
                for (var d:int = 0; d < doors.length; d++)
                    newArr[(doors[d].y - 25) / 50][(doors[d].x - 25) / 50] = [doors[d].des,doors[d].unlocked];
                styles[current] = newArr; /* errors will ocur because this part is duplicate*/
            }
            bullets = [];
            blocks = [];
            coins = [];
            coins2 = [];
            enemies = [];
            keys = [];
            doors = [];
            ladders = [];
            redwater1 = [];
            bluewater1 = [];
            /*char.floor = 450;*/
            for (var i:int = 0; i < maps[0].length; i++)
            {
                for ( var j:int = 0; j < maps[0][0].length; j++)
                {
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        var block:Block = new Block();
                        /*insert code from video part 15 (12:18)*/
                        block.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        block.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        if (getQualifiedClassName(styles[index][i][j] == "Array"))
                        {
                            block.xSpeed = styles[index][i][j][1];
                            block.ySpeed = styles[index][i][j][2];
                            block.xDist = styles[index][i][j][3];
                            block.yDist = styles[index][i][j][4];
                            block.xHome = block.x;
                            block.yHome = block.y;
                            block.mover = true;
                        }
                        blocks.push(block);
                        cam.addChild(block);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 2)
                    {
                        var coin:Coin = new Coin();
                        coin.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        coin.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        coins.push(coin);
                        cam.addChild(coin);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 7)
                    {
                        var coin2:Coin2 = new Coin2();
                        coin2.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        coin2.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        coins.push(coin2);
                        cam.addChild(coin2);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 3)
                    {
                        var enem:Enemy = new Enemy(enemyNames[enemies.length]);
                        enem.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        enem.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        enemies.push(enem);
                        cam.addChild(enem);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 4)
                    {
                        var key:Key = new Key();
                        key.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        key.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        /*cam.addChild(key);*/
                        keys.push(key);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 5)
                    {
                        var ladder:Ladder = new Ladder(false);
                        ladder.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        ladder.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        cam.addChild(ladder);
                        ladders.push(ladder);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 6)
                    {
                        var ladder:Ladder = new Ladder(true);
                        ladder.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        ladder.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        cam.addChild(ladder);
                        ladders.push(ladder);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] >= 8)
                    {
                        var door:Door = new Door(styles[index][i][j][0]);
                        door.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        door.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        door.unlocked = styles[index][i][j][1];
                        if (door.dest == current)
                        {
                            char.x = door.x;
                            char.y = door.y;
                            char.floor = 10000;
                        }
                        cam.addChild(door);
                        doors.push(door);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 11)
                    {
                        var redwaters:RedWater = new RedWater();
                        redwaters.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        redwaters.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        redwater1.push(redwaters);
                        cam.addChild(redwaters);
                    }
                    if (maps[index][i][j] == 12)
                    {
                        var bluewaters:BlueWater = new BlueWater();
                        bluewaters.x = j * 50 + 25;
                        bluewaters.y = i * 50 + 25;
                        bluewater1.push(bluewaters);
                        cam.addChild(bluewaters);
                    }
                }
            }
            cam.addChild(char);
            cam.addChild(char2);
            mapIndex = index;
        }
        public function mDown(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            var ang:Number = 0;
            if (mouseX > 400)
                ang = (Math.atan(((mouseY - cam.y) - char.y) / ((mouseX - cam.x) - char.x)));
            else 
                ang = -1 * (Math.atan(((mouseY - cam.y) - char.y) / ((mouseX - cam.x) - char.x)));
            var xSpeed:Number = Math.cos(ang) * 45;
            var ySpeed:Number = Math.sin(ang) * 45;
            if(mouseX<400)
                xSpeed *= -1;
            var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(char.x, char.y, xSpeed, ySpeed);
            cam.addChild(bullet)
            bullets.push(bullet)
        }/*code for shooting bullets*/
        public function m2Down(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            var ang:Number = 0;
            if (mouseX > 400)
                ang = (Math.atan(((mouseY - cam.y) - char2.y) / ((mouseX - cam.x) - char2.x)));
            else 
                ang = -1 * (Math.atan(((mouseY - cam.y) - char2.y) / ((mouseX - cam.x) - char2.x)));
            var xSpeed:Number = Math.cos(ang) * 45;
            var ySpeed:Number = Math.sin(ang) * 45;
            if(mouseX<400)
                xSpeed *= -1;
            var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(char2.x, char2.y, xSpeed, ySpeed);
            cam.addChild(bullet)
            bullets.push(bullet)
        }/*code for shooting bullets*/
        public function check(e:Event):void
        {   
            textBox.text = "Score: " + score;
            keyTextBox.text = "Keys: " + keyCount;
            hp.scaleX = char.health / 100;
            hp2.scaleX = char2.health / 100;
            if (char.health > 0)
            {
                hp.scaleX = char.health / 100;
            }
            else
            {
                hp.scaleX = 0;
                End();
            }
            if (enemies.length > 0)
            {
                enhp.scaleX = enemies[current].health / 100;
                enemyNameBox.text = enemies[current].name2;
            }
            else 
            {
                enhp.scaleX = 0;
                enemyNameBox.text = "All enemies cleared";
            }
            var prevX:int = char.x; 
            var prevY:int = char.y;
            var prevX:int = char2.x; 
            var prevY:int = char2.y;

            for ( var i:int = 0; i < blocks.length; i++)
            {
                blocks[i].CheckObj(char, i);
                blocks[i].CheckObj(char2, i);
                if (blocks[i].mover)
                    blocks[i].adjust(char, i);
                for (var s:int = 0; s < enemies.length; s++)
                    blocks[i].CheckObj(enemies[s], i);
            }
            if (aDown)
                char.x -= 5;
                /*cam.x += 5;*/
            if (dDown)
                char.x += 5;
                /*cam.x -= 5; the camera moves along with the ball but it keeps meoving when the ball hits the wall*/
            if (leftDown)
                char2.x -= 5;
                /*cam.x += 5;*/
            if (rightDown)
                char2.x += 5;
            if(!climbing)
            {
                char.adjust();
                char2.adjust();
            }
            else 
            {
                if (wDown)
                    char.y -= 5;
                if (sDown)
                    char.y += 5;
            }
            for ( var j:int = enemies.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                var result:int = enemies[j].CheckObj(char || char2 , bullets);
                if(result== -1)
                {   
                    cam.removeChild(enemies[j])
                    enemies.splice(j, 1);
                    current = 0;
                    score += 10;
                }else 
                if (result != -2)
                {
                    cam.removeChild(bullets[result]);
                    bullets.splice(result, 1);
                    current = j;
                }
            }
            for ( var k:int = 0; k < bullets.length; k++)
            {
                bullets[k].check();
            }
            /*cam--; this code moves the screen to the right*/
            for ( var s:int = coins.length-1; s >= 0; s--)
            {
                if (coins[s].CheckObj(char))
                {
                    cam.removeChild(coins[s]);
                    coins.splice(s, 1);
                    score++;
                }
            }
            for ( var s:int = coins2.length-1; s >= 0; s--)
            {
                if (coins2[s].CheckObj(char2))
                {
                    cam.removeChild(coins2[s]);
                    coins2.splice(s, 1);
                    score++;
                }
            }
            for (var d:int = 0; d < doors.length; d++)
            {
                if (!doors[d].unlocked)
                    keyCount--;
                doors[d].unlocked = true;
                loadMap(doors[d].dest,mapIndex);

            }
            for (var w:int = 0; w < keys.length; w++)
            {
                if (keys[w].CheckObj(char , enemies) == 1)
                {
                    cam.addChild(keys[w]);
                    keys[w].vis = true;
                }
                if (keys[w].CheckObj(char , enemies)==2)
                {
                    cam.removeChild(keys[w]);
                    keys.splice(w, 1);
                    keyCount++;
                }
            }
            for (var l:int = 0; l < ladders.length; l++)
            {
                (ladders[l].CheckObj(char, 1, climbing));
            }
            /*cam.x -= char.x - prevX;
            cam.y -= char.y - prevY;*/ /*camera follows the player*/
            spaceDown = false;
        }
        public function keysDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 65)
                aDown = true;
            if (e.keyCode == 68)
                dDown = true;
            if (e.keyCode == 87&&((char.y+char.width/2==char.floor)|| char.onLadder !=-1))
            {   
                if(char.onLadder==-1)
                    char.grav = -15;
                else
                {
                    climbing = true;
                    wDown = true;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 83)
            {
                if (char.onLadder != -1)
                    climbing = true;
                sDown = true;
            }
        }
        public function keysUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 65)
                aDown = false;
            if (e.keyCode == 68)
                dDown = false;
            if (e.keyCode == 83)
                sDown = false;
            if (e.keyCode == 87)
                wDown = false;
        }
        public function keysDown2(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
                leftDown = true;
            if (e.keyCode == 39)
                rightDown = true;
            if (e.keyCode == 38&&char2.y+char2.width/2==char2.floor)
                char2.grav = -15;
        }
        public function keysUp2(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
                leftDown = false;
            if (e.keyCode == 39)
                rightDown = false;
        }
        public function End():void
        {
            removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
            removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keysUp);
            removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown2);
            removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keysUp2);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, m2Down);
            Mouse.show();
            ShowEnd.text = "You died";
            addChild(ShowEnd);
            ShowEnd.width = 300;
            Restart = new Replay();
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartgame);
            addChild(Restart);
        }
        public function restartgame(e:Event):void
        {
            removeChild(Restart);
            removeChild(ShowEnd);
            keyCount = 0;
            score = 0;
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartgame);
            init();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to complain that your code is a mess.
You should refactor your code into several classes to reduce duplicated code etc.

On to the problem.
The line in question is this one:

```
block.xSpeed = styles[index][i][j][1];
```

To keep things simple, I assume index, i and j to be 0.
Let's take a look at how styles is defined:

```
private var styles:Array = [
    [
    [0, //and so on
```

With the assumptions above:
`styles[0][0][0]` is the number 0 in the snippet above. Adding `[1]` to the end of the line tries to find a property 1 in this number, which does not exist.

Instead of nesting arrays into each other endlessly, build datastructures that describe the data best.
Do not operate on the raw data, but provide methods to access it in the datastructures.

Instead of `map[i][j]`,do something like this: `map.get(i, j)` This allows you to test this function on its own, throw errors on bad parameter values, etc.

I also recommend to serialise/deserialize the data into objects. Instead of some number, in some array, you can read properties. This makes the code a lot more readable.